# Horizontal navigation with sub-nav problems

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a Horizontal menu with a single line drop down sub nav.
When I rollover my main navigation links it displays the sub nav but pushes the rest of the content to the right. I would like the submenu to appear to the far left of the main menu and for it not to affect the main menu. Thanks!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfrank44/8GYbh/5/)

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">LINK1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">LINK3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK6</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK8</a></li>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
display:block;
list-style:none;
text-align: left;
}
#nav a{
width: 50px;
height: 15px;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
font-size:12px;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
color:#666666;
border-left: 1px solid #999999; 
float:left; 
padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:focus {
background: #999 ;
color:#333;
}
#nav li { 
height: 30px;
display:block;
position:relative;
float:left;
}
#nav li ul { 
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
position: relative;
left: 0;
clear: both;
}
#nav li li a{
width: 50px;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
font-size:9px;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
border-left: 1px solid #999999; 
color:#666666;
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
z-index: 10000;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few changes and it's working, mainly:

```
#nav li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-spacing: -1em;
    clear: both;
}
#nav li li {
    word-spacing: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/8GYbh/7/)

Comment: Hi Itay is there a way to have the sub menu over to the far left? so it's arranged with the left side of the main menu? left:0; doesn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use it too

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8GYbh/9/

```
#nav li { 
    height: 30px;
    display:inline;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    clear: both;
    top:45px;
}
```

Comment: display inline and float left will render as display block which is already the `li` default